# Can you perform somatic components with War Caster when wielding a single weapon or shield?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, grapple, spellcasting

Reading the [War Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/war-caster) feat again, I'm having a doubt about the following sentence:

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

I'm trying to figure out the implications of this feat when using a hand to grapple an opponent. It looks like wielding a shield would be enough to perform somatic components, but wielding a single weapon would not - the plural suggesting you must hold 2 weapons (potentially, in one hand...) to do so.

Am I reading this correctly, or am I paying my lack of involvement during english lessons ?

*More context: I'm considering spells such as [Primal Savagery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/primal-savagery), [Shocking Grasp](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shocking-grasp), [Inflict Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/inflict-wounds), [Vampiric Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch) to deal reasonable damage to a grappled, prone opponent, while wearing a shield. Double-checking RAW here, and adding the "weapons" issue for the sake of completeness.*

Answer (score 6):

To cast a spell with somatic [components](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Components) you need at least one hand free:

> If a spell requires a somatic component, the caster must have free use of at least one hand to perform these gestures.

Warcaster amends this rule::

> You can perform the somatic components of spells even when you have weapons or a shield in one or both hands.

If you have a weapon or shield in one or both hands, you can still use somatic components. You can parse the sentence as: (weapon or shield) in (one or both) hands. The sentence is a bit funky because it says plural "weapons" and singular "a shield". This leads to a bit of a weird situation:

Weapon in one hand? Fine.

Shield in one hand? Fine.

Weapon and shield? Fine.

2 weapons? Fine.

2 handing a weapon? Fine, and perhaps useful because you don't have to let go of the weapon.

2 shields? Not fine, since it says "a shield"

1 shield held in two hands? Fine but weird.

[Grappling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) uses at least one hand:

> Using at least one free hand, you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an attack roll ...

If you are grappling with one hand, and holding a weapon or shield with the other, then since you "have a weapon or a shield in one or both hands" you can still use War Caster to perform somatic components.

Comment: Genuinely never noticed that you couldn't do this if you wield two shields, though that would rarely ever come up, good to know.

Comment: @Medix2 honestly, the intent is probably that you could do it with a shield in each hand, but the rules always assume that you don't wield two shields at once - all the rules are written as if you'll _never_ hold more than one shield, but this being DnD, a dual-shield subclass is bound to come out soon....

Comment: @gatherer818 i agree. Also one the reasons it says shield in the singular is may be because multiple shields do not stack in the AC, therefore they didn't mention the possibility.

Comment: That plural really puzzles me. If you have 2 shields in 2 hands, you *also* have 1 shield in 1 hand, don't you? I don't get how it doesn't qualify...

Comment: @Bash It's a ridiculous situation. YMMV, your DM has to decide whether dual wielding shields is "a shield in one hand" (qualified), or "two shields in both hands" (not qualified). I think this is a rare case of terrible wording. Your DM would need to be quite petty to deny that you can cast while dual wielding shields.